# Regex: find two consonants together but not in a list

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to find two consonants together between two vowels but these consonants should not be in a list:

For instance, my black-list is (br|bl|cn|cr)

```
between = It's good because 'tw' is not in the list.
abroad = it's wrong because 'br' is in the black-list.
```

But I need only the two last pair consonant-vowel:

```
between = I only need 'we' no 'et'.
```

I have the following regex, but I don't know how to check if the captured consonant is in the list.

```
"[aeiou]([^aeiou]{2})[aeiou]"
```

I captured the consonants with "([^aeiou]{2})", but how do I check if the capture "\1" is in the black-list?

Comment: Looks like you need `^(?!.*(?:br|bl|cn|cr)).*[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]{2}`.

Comment: There should be negative-lookahead or negative-lookbehind non-capcture group in regex engine.

Comment: @Aaron same for your answer... can you give a small example?

Comment: Hi @jhnc, same for your answer. You're right, my mistake... I made the change.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks for your answer. Your answer is good, but if I have "bandwidth abroad" in the same line, the regex doesn't match with "nd", "dw", "dt", "the": I need only the consonants that match not the word. I appreciate your comments.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew maybe... "[aeiou](?!(?:br|bl|cn|cr))[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]{2}[aeiou]"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this regex works fine! "[aeiou](?!(?:br|bl|cn|cr))[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]([b-df-hj-np-tv-z][aeiou])". In the text "watson" this matches with "atso", it'great! but maybe you can help me with this question? how do I take only "so", that is I only need the second consonat and the last vowel, I want to discard "at".

Comment: You just use first capture group in your suggested regex or use `(?<=[aeiou](?!(?:br|bl|cn|cr))[b-df-hj-np-tv-z])[b-df-hj-np-tv-z][aeiou]`

Comment: @JaimeCamargo A shorter version: `(?<=[aeiou](?!b[rl]|c[nr])[b-df-hj-np-tv-z])[b-df-hj-np-tv-z][aeiou]`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/KF3v6X/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot... I posted your answer and your credits. I appreciate if you can vote 'thumb-up' my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
(?<=[aeiou](?!(?:br|bl|cn|cr))[b-df-hj-np-tv-z])[b-df-hj-np-tv-z][aeiou]
(?<=[aeiou](?!(?:b[rl]|c[nr]))[b-df-hj-np-tv-z])[b-df-hj-np-tv-z][aeiou]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KF3v6X/1)

*Details*

- `(?<=[aeiou](?!(?:br|bl|cn|cr))[b-df-hj-np-tv-z])` - a positive lookbehind that requires a lowercase ASCII vowel letter and then an ASCII lowercase consonant letter that is not a starting point of a `br`, `bl`, `cn` or `cr` char sequences
- `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]`  - a consonant lowercase ASCII letter
- `[aeiou]` - a lowercase ASCII vowel letter